# jupyter note book error because of unknown reason

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
from scipy.io import wavfile

train_audio_path = 'E:\'
filename = 'file_example_WAV_1MG'
sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read(train_audio_path + filename)
print('sample rate : {}, samples.shape : {}'.format(sample_rate, samples.shape))
```

this is my code and I have two problems.
when i keep using this code, an error

```
  File "<ipython-input-7-ebdfbc596537>", line 3
    train_audio_path = "E:\"
                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

comes out

and when i use / instead of \,

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-cd74bbc41446> in <module>
      3 train_audio_path = 'E:/'
      4 filename = 'file_example_WAV_1MG'
----> 5 sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read(train_audio_path + filename)
      6 print('sample rate : {}, samples.shape : {}'.format(sample_rate, samples.shape))

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py in read(filename, mmap)
    262         mmap = False
    263     else:
--> 264         fid = open(filename, 'rb')
    265 
    266     try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/file_example_WAV_1MG'
```

this error comes out. what is wrong in my code? I can't find at all..

Answer (score 0):

The antislash character is special in python.

Try `train_audio_path = 'E:\\'
print(train_audio_path)`
output: `E:\`

Comment: well I found the reason. it was because I didn't right extension in my file! but since i had corrected my code, this error is coming out again.(i dont know whether i can call it an error because code is working fine) E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:7: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  import sys